# Stop the loop when reaching the empty column

Tags: python-3.x, csv, for-loop

I am working on a XLSX file converted to CSV file, that has several columns of data.
There is no space between each column and, of course, after the last column, there are only empty cells.
I am looping through each row, and through each column, up to the last one. I'm printing each column of data.
Up to this point, everything OK.

I copy here the part of the script in which the loop starts to examine all the columns:

```
start= 0
for line in myfile:
    for col in line:
        if col:
            print("e.g.: PRINTED")
            start+= 1
        elif not col:
            break
```

I achieved to print all the columns but after the last one, I get

`IndexError: list index out of range`

I don't get why it successes to print up to the last column (as I want) but after that it doesn't stop but throws this error.

I hope this is clearly written.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Marco because after the last column that you are reading you are trying to iterate once more

```
start+= 1
```

. This problem can be solved by tweaking your loop a little bit.

- Use for loop instead foreach loop.
- put your iteration somewhere else.

Comment: Oh my. You are right! :facepalm:
I'll modify that line. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using a specific excel package, but some (like XLRD) have ncols or nrows (number of columns & rows) methods attributed to the sheet that can be used so you only iterate over the number of columns or rows.

e.g. for x in range(sheet.ncols):
          do something

May be useful for the future!

Comment: Thank you. I'll give a try to this package as well!